# Calculate delta columns within one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe labeled as following:

```
a_col1 a_col2 a_col3 ID name b_col1 b_col2 b_col3
```

I am trying to generate new columns delta1, delta2, delta3

```
delta1 = b_col3 - a_col3
delta2 = b_col2 - a_col2
delta3 = b_col1 - a_col1
```

I currently use `df['delta3'] = df['b_col3'] - df['a_col3']`

Is there any easy way to create a loop that I don't have to iterate through col1 to col3

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
df[['delta1','delta2','delta3']] = df.filter(like='a_').sub(df.filter(like='b_').values)
```

Comment: FYI, for accessing a series, [`.values` will be deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#whatsnew-0240-values-api)

Answer (score 0):

So your `a_col*` columns have indices 0..2, `b_col*` are 5..7 and `delta*` will be 8..10

```
# Create new columns, na for pessimism
df[['delta1','delta2','delta3']] = np.nan

# Now compute their values
for i in range(3):
    df.iloc[:, 8+i] = df.iloc[:, 5+i] - df.iloc[:, i]
```

Really you could do the latter in one vectorized assignment:

```
df.iloc[:, [8,9,10]] = df.iloc[:, [5,6,7]] - df.iloc[:, [0,1,2]]
```

or just:

```
df[['delta1','delta2','delta3']] = df.iloc[:, [5,6,7]] - df.iloc[:, [0,1,2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `eval`

Separated string assignments with newline

```
evalstr = """\
delta1 = a_col1 - b_col1
delta2 = a_col2 - b_col2
delta3 = a_col3 - b_col3
"""
df.eval(evalstr)

   a_col1  a_col2  a_col3    ID  name  b_col1  b_col2  b_col3  delta1  delta2  delta3
0      10       9       8  this  that       5       6       7       5       3       1
```

---

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a_col1': [10], 'a_col2': [9], 'a_col3': [8],
    'ID': ['this'], 'name': ['that'],
    'b_col1': [5], 'b_col2': [6], 'b_col3': [7],
})
```